# Max-width on images and inline-block in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, fluid-layout

I'm trying to make an image fit a container, with a wrapping div that fits to the width of the image. I can do this succesfully, but when I set the max-width of the image to 100% (to make sure it fits into containing div) it doesn't work in IE9/IE8 (image is displayed at full width). Works fine in Chrome. Max width works when wrapper div isn't set to inline-block. I tried with floating the two elements as well, that didn't work either.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbgWv/.

Comment: This is also an issue in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `width:100%;` to the img.

Comment: This worked! I assumed this would set the image size to the width of the container, but it didn't.

Comment: Thanks for this. Any idea what is happening and why? 
I created a Codepen to test: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/MYadRO (view full page in IE8: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/full/MYadRO)
Also, is there any better fix?

Answer (score -1):

IE is quite often the odd one out :D

Try giving the image an absolute width value, like I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N69mw/).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately I want this CSS to apply to images with variable width, and I also want them to expand to the outer container, so I can't use an absolute width without using JS

Comment: Yeah, I think in this case you can't really get away without using JavaScript to detect IE and specify your width.